# Is uninitialized_copy() exception-safe?

Tags: c++, exception, exception-safety

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctht4stc.aspx) and [other places](http://books.google.com/books?id=gYNVsCaxfYgC&lpg=PA380&ots=KLUIn19QsP&dq=uninitialized_copy%20exception&pg=PA380#v=onepage&q=uninitialized_copy%20exception&f=false) say that `uninitialized_copy` provides a strong exception guarantee, but [other](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/uninitialized_copy.html) C++ references [don't](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/uninitialized_copy/).

Is this in fact guaranteed by C++, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, C++03 does provide this guarantee, but **it's worth double-checking** for your implementations.

From a draft copy I had on my machine, 20.4.4:

> All the iterators that are used as formal template parameters in the following algorithms are required to have their `operator*` return an object for which operator& is defined and returns a pointer to `T`.
>   In the algorithm `uninitialized_copy`, the formal template parameter `InputIterator` is required to satisfy the requirements of an input iterator (24.1.1).
>   In all of the following algorithms, the formal template parameter `ForwardIterator` is required to satisfy the requirements of a forward iterator (24.1.3) and also to satisfy the requirements of a mutable iterator (24.1), and is required to have the property that no exceptions are thrown from increment, assignment, comparison, or dereference of valid iterators.
>   **In the following algorithms, if an exception is thrown there are no effects.**
>
> - `uninitialized_copy`  (etc.)

So yes, that means the "possible implementation" you see on [some pages](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy_n) can be incorrect.

Comment: **2023 update:** Note that the strong exception guarantee requirement has been removed from `std::uninitialized_copy` and other specialized memory algorithms as well: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3054. There is an exemplary case, another one I can think of would be a copy constructor that modifies the source (having a non-const reference parameter). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Kdx337b6s.